# Usar dois code::blocks ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: codeblocks

Alguém sabe com usar dois code::blocks ao mesmo tempo?
Cada vez que tento abrir dois apenas fica o último aberto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir ter múltiplos CodeBlocks abertos ao mesmo tempo precisa desmarcar duas opções:

- Settings > Environment > Allow only one running instance
- Settings > Environment > Use an already running instance

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A alteração só tem efeito após reiniciar o programa!

Após isso pode abrir quantos CodeBlocks quiser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Kuddos extras por mostrar cinco code::blocks simultâneos \o/